# Can I make Asynchronous ODBC Calls? Any reference materials?

Tags: c++, sql, database, asynchronous, odbc

Does ODBC support asynchronous calls? If it does, then can you tell me about any reference materials?

My preferred language is C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've wanted to know the exact same thing. An obvious workaround is to maintain a pool of threads that each perform synchronous ODBC calls and are signalled (and signal back) asynchronously.

Comment: What I've found out today is this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/asyncrecordset.aspx

It's an MFC example of making ODBC calls asynchronously, where each query waits on a thread, the request can be canceled but it's not REALLY an asynchronous query where we get chunks of data.

Comment: Asynchronous is in the eye of the beholder!

Answer (score 5):

This MSDN article could be a starting point for you: [Executing Statements ODBC:
Asynchronous Execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713563.aspx)

From the article:

> ODBC 3.8 in the Windows 7 SDK introduced asynchronous execution on connection-related operations ... an application determined that the asynchronous operation was complete using the polling method. Beginning in the Windows 8 SDK, you can determine that an asynchronous operation is complete using the notification method.

Answer (score 0):

Typically it seems like such things are implemented at another abstraction level of an application, or you roll your own. Just about anything that involves a blockable "open" action can spawn a thread for the purpose of managing the open and raising a signal or setting a flag somewhere globally when it happens.

Some frameworks are pretty good about offering both flavors. Flex comes to mind, where it's helpful for it to play the tricks with the single browser/javascript/swf thread.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous ODBC functions is feature provided by ODBC driver.

Pre ODBC3.8 only statement related calls could be async-enabled. Starting ODBC3.8 connection related function calls can also be made async-enabled.

Of course we can implement any missing functionality at applications side but having it implemented at driver makes things less painful on application side.

I am looking for a comprehensive list of driver which clearly states if a driver supports async calls out-of-the-box. Please point to me to such a list if anyone is aware of it.